# Running Multiple Redis Sentinels through ServiceStack

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm working on a project that is using a Redis Sentinel through Servicestack. When the project was set up the original developer used Redis for both Caching and for maintaining a series of queue that power the logic of the system. Due to performance issues we are planning to spin up a new Redis Sentinel box and split the functionalities with the Caching being done on one server, and the queuing being done on another.

I was able to make a couple small changes to a local instance I had to split it between two servers by using the RedisClient and the PooledClient

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new RedisManagerPool(redCon, poolConfig));
container.Register<PooledRedisClientManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(redCon2Test));    

container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetClient());
container.Register(c => c.Resolve<PooledRedisClientManager>().GetClient());
 // REDIS CACHE
container.Register(c => c.Resolve<PooledRedisClientManager>().GetCacheClient());

// SESSION
container.Register(c => new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

// REDIS MQ
container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RedisMqServer(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>())
    {
        DisablePriorityQueues = true,
        DisablePublishingResponses = true,
        RetryCount = 2
    });
container.Register(q => q.Resolve<IMessageService>().MessageFactory);
this.RegisterHandlers(container.Resolve<IMessageService>() as RedisMqServer);
```

The problem though is I don't have Redis Sentinel set up on the machine I'm using, and when I tried to drop a Sentinel Connection in as a PooledRedis Connection, I receive compilation errors on the second start. It will let me cast it as a PooledRedisClientManager, but I wasn't sure if Pooled vs Sentinel was even something that would play well together to begin with

```
if (useSentinel)
{
    var hosts = redCon.Split(',');
    var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(hosts, masterName)
       {
           RedisManagerFactory = CreateRedisManager,
           ScanForOtherSentinels = false,
           SentinelWorkerConnectTimeoutMs = 150,
           OnWorkerError = OnWorkerError,
           OnFailover = OnSentinelFailover,
           OnSentinelMessageReceived = (x, y) => Log.Debug($"MSG: {x} DETAIL: {y}")
       };
    container.Register(c => sentinel.Start());


    var hosts2 = redCon.Split(',');
    var sentinel2 = new RedisSentinel(hosts2, masterName)
       {
           RedisManagerFactory = CreatePooledRedisClientManager,
           ScanForOtherSentinels = false,
           SentinelWorkerConnectTimeoutMs = 150,
           OnWorkerError = OnWorkerError,
           OnFailover = OnSentinelFailover,
           OnSentinelMessageReceived = (x, y) => Log.Debug($"MSG: {x} DETAIL: {y}")
       };
    
    container.Register<PooledRedisClientManager>(c => sentinel2.Start());
}
```

But honestly, I'm not sure if this is even the correct way to be trying to go about this. Should I even be using the Pooled manager at all? Is there a good way to register two different Redis Sentinel servers in the Container and split them in the way I am attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack only allows 1 `IRedisClientsManager` implementation per AppHost, if you're using [RedisSentinel](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-sentinel) its `.Start()` method will return a pre-configured `PooledRedisClientManager` that utilizes the `RedisSentinel` configuration.

If you wanted `RedisMqServer` to use a different RedisSentinel cluster you should avoid duplicating Redis registrations in the IOC and just configure it directly with RedisMqServer, e.g:

```
container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RedisMqServer(sentinel2.Start())
{
    DisablePriorityQueues = true,
    DisablePublishingResponses = true,
    RetryCount = 2
});
```

However given `RedisSentinel` typically [requires 6 nodes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/Redis-Sentinel#configure-redis-sentinel-servers) for setting up a minimal highly available configuration it seems counter productive to double the required infrastructure resources just to have a separate Sentinel Cluster for RedisMQ especially when the load for using Redis as a message transport should be negligible compared to the compute resources to process the messages. What’s the MQ throughput? You should verify the load on Redis servers is the bottleneck as it’s very unlikely.

I would recommend avoiding this duplicated complexity and use a different RedisMQ Server like see if [Background MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/background-mq) is an option where MQ Requests are executed in Memory in Background Threads, if you need to use a distributed MQ look at [Rabbit MQ](https://docs.servicestack.net/rabbit-mq) which is purpose built for the task and would require a lot less maintenance than trying to manage 2 separate RedisSentinel cluster configurations.

Comment: Thanks, right now I'm being very pushed towards the two Sentinels plan, so I'm going to give the RedisMqServer direct configuration idea a shot once they finish getting the environment all configured. I'm marking this answered, but may hit you up for ideas later if I have any issues.

Comment: Hey mythz, small update on this (and a quick question), we tried to move to Memcached for our caching service, but our values often exceed the 1 MB limit. Is there a build in flag or anything to be able to easily compress what goes into the cache? All the compression information I can find on ServiceStack is oriented towards what is going across the network rather than what goes in/out of the cache

Comment: @lasernick No there's no compression built into redis or cache clients, you'd need to perform the de/compression yourself using raw byte[] APIs in [IRedisNativeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisNativeClient.cs).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information